# JMC maxage/maxsize doesn't work

Tags: java, performance, intellij-idea, jmc, jfr

According to [JAVA cmd Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html) I can set maxage and/or maxsize of JFR recording but it doesn't work.

I've shared Intellij IDEA recording and compilation of scala using ant: [Stats](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B6VELd5wVsAybGJwMW0zLUlsaGM&usp=sharing)

For idea I had the following settings:

> -XX:+FlightRecorder -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=defaultrecording=true,disk=true,dumponexit=true,dumponexitpath=/home/ichaki/development/misc/stats/idea,maxage=1h,repository=/home/ichaki/development/misc/stats/idea,settings=profile

For ant:

> -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=defaultrecording=true,disk=true,dumponexit=true,dumponexitpath=/home/ichaki/development/misc/stats/scala-ant,maxage=120s,maxsize=200k,repository=/home/ichaki/development/misc/stats/scala-ant,settings=profile

Thanks!

Note: I want to make stat collection in envs with SSD's which are quite limited in size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flight Recorder writes data in chunks to disk, about 12-15 Mb each by default, so it's not possible to set a maxsize below that threshold.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the chunksize smaller, I'm not sure how small would be recommendable.

Comment: It's not possible to set it below 1 MB.

Answer (score 0):

As a comment to @kire-haglin answer:

> Flight Recorder writes data in chunks to disk, about 12-15 Mb each by
> default, so it's not possible to set a maxsize below that threshold.

If there are limitations for the accepted command line parameter values for JFR, then why these invalid values are silently accepted on start-up of the JVM (or by the jcmd tool)?
It is not very user-friendly behaviour.